# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions due to closure - no transitions or segues involved

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have three view controllers.

The first two view controllers use a navigation controller.

The third view controller is displayed modally.

The first view controller displays the second view controller using a segue in the storyboard, so there is no code involved here.

When the second view controller displays the third view controller modally and pops itself to the first view controller, using `popToRootViewController`, I get the error message:

`Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for SecondViewController`

The code of the second view controller presenting the third view controller and popping to the first view controller is like this:

```
        if let thirdViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdViewControllerID") {
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: thirdViewController)
            self.navigationController?.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: {
            _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
        })
```

The line of code causing the problem in the second view controller is:

```
_ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
```

[The source code showing the error is available here.](https://bitbucket.org/JackG/display-view-controller-with-done-button-programmatically/branch/Unbalanced_calls_to_begin%2Fend_appearance_transitions_for)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in the second view controller to call `popToRootViewController` outside the completion block of the `navigationcontroller.present` method like this:

```
    if let thirdViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdViewControllerID") {
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: thirdViewController)
        self.navigationController?.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    }
```

**Notice the popToRootViewController is not anymore part of the UINavigationViewController.present(completion:) closure but is now outside and this solves the problem.**

[The source code with the fix is available here.](https://bitbucket.org/JackG/display-view-controller-with-done-button-programmatically/branch/Unbalanced_calls_to_begin%2Fend_appearance_transitions_for)